# How to create a shared memory mapping that is read-only for other processes?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory, mmap

I have a forking setuid program in which the parent process creates an anonymous, read-only shared memory mapping.
But the unprivileged child process can simply change the memory protection and alter the memory! (See example below)

How do I disallow this? Is that possible with anonymous mappings or do I need shm_open/shmget?

Compiled and run with `g++ -Wall -Wextra test.cpp && sudo ./a.out`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    size_t len = 4096;
    char* data = (char*)mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ, MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    volatile unsigned* shared_value = (unsigned*)data;
    if (fork() > 0) { // Parent process
        cout << "[Parent] uid=" << getuid() << endl;
        usleep(2000000);
        cout << "[Parent] value is " << *shared_value << endl;
        usleep(2000000);
        cout << "[Parent] value is " << *shared_value << endl;
    } else { // Child process
        usleep(1000000);
        cout << "[Child]  uid=" << getuid() << endl;
        if (setuid(1000) < 0) {
            perror("setuid");
        }
        cout << "[Child]  uid=" << getuid() << endl;
        if (mprotect(data, len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) < 0) {
            perror("mprotect");
        }
        usleep(2000000);
        *shared_value = 456;
        cout << "[Child]  changed value" << endl;
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
[Parent] uid=0
[Child]  uid=0
[Child]  uid=1000
[Parent] value is 0
[Child]  changed value
[Parent] value is 456
```

Comment: you might be interested in `fcntl(fd, F_ADD_SEALS, ...)`

Comment: "_the unprivileged child process_" - The child process should have the same privileges as the parent process unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: The parent process has user ID 0, the child process has user ID 1000.